# Constants and Matlab Coder

Tags: matlab, constants, matlab-coder

Some functions requires the input to be a constant, when run in Matlab Coder. **I wish to find a way to declare the input as a constant before it is input** as an example for the problematic situation:

```
  function foo = subsubfunction(x,y)            
      [B,A]=butter(1,x/y);
```

This will return the error *'All inputs must be constant'*

How do I declare **x and y as constants so that butter() gets happy?** I have tried many solutions and unfortunately not found anything really satisfying. If the command line operation `coder.newtype('constant',x)` could be used it would simplify everything.

Comment: do you really mean constant or just one value and not a vector/array ? you could use the `numel` function...

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer! But how do you mean that I could use `numel` to solve this problem? In which way will that ensure matlab that the input is constant?

Answer (score 2):

Use `coder.const` in the function, so that the function `butter` knows you are passing a constant input. The documentation is available [here](http://mathworks.nl/help/simulink/slref/coder.const.html).

```
 function foo = subsubfunction(x,y)            
  [B,A]=coder.const(@butter,1,x/y);
```

**Note**: You cannot change the value of `x/y` in the generated code. You could individually change `x` and `y`, but not the ratio of the two numbers.

Comment: The documentation you refer to requires a login, please check whether this one is similar and consider updating the link: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/simulink/slref/coder.const.html

Comment: Does not work for me, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202957/matlab-coder-all-inputs-must-be-constant